# IdentityModel: Getting UserInfo from access token via IdentityServer

Tags: c#, webforms, identityserver4, dotnet-httpclient, identitymodel

I have identity server([IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/)) setup and running as localhost.
My client project is *AspNet WebForms* at this moment. There is another application(javascript) which uses same identity server.

This javascript application calls my webform application and provides accessToken provided via IdentityServer.

Now, I want to call the userInfo endpoint to get openId and profile scope.

I am doing as mentioned in documentation [documentation](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/userinfo.html) hoping to get userInfo using [IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel). But I am not able to get any user info at this point. Below is the sample response from identityserver

[image]

Here is the code as mentioned in the documentation

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        var httpclient = new HttpClient();
        var token = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Get("Authorization");
        var response = httpclient.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest
        {              
            Address = "https://localhost:44367/connect/userinfo",
            Token = token

        });
        if (response.IsFaulted)
        {

        }
    }
```

Do I somehow also have to provide clientId while making request to identityServer?
And, ny idea what is going wrong and how can I get the userInfo from the accessToken.

Please do notice that my client in Asp.Net webform project

Comment: For starter, you need to await the async method for getuserinfo

Comment: I think the token that you're sending is incorrect, it shouldn't include the "Bearer" part.